# Como pegar a foto tirada da camera, e não o preview da camera

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Boa tarde pessoal, estou utilizando [esse projeto de camera multiplataforma do xamarin.](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/ContentPage/Droid/CameraPageRenderer.cs)

Na parte do android, não estou conseguindo máximo na foto, estou utilizando esta função:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList<Android.Hardware.Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.SupportedPictureSizes;

    // Iterate through all available resolutions and choose one.
    // The chosen resolution will be stored in mSize.

    foreach (var size in sizes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Available resolution: " + size.Width + " " + size.Height);
        mSize = size;
        if (1920 <= size.Width & size.Height <= 1944)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chosen resolution: " + mSize.Width + " " + mSize.Height);

            parameters.SetPictureSize(mSize.Width, mSize.Height);
            orgPreviewWidth = mSize.Width;
            orgPreviewHeight = mSize.Height;

        }
```

ele esta pegando a resolução que eu quero, mais eu notei que na hora de salvar a foto, salva com o tamanho do preview da macera, que varia de celular para celular, pois ele gera um Bitmap do `Preview(TextureView)`

Aqui eu passo o tamanho do preview, se eu por a resolução da foto que desejo, a tela fica todo esticada

```
textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(widht, height);
```

Para salvar a foto:

```
var image = textureView.Bitmap;
var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
var folderPath = absolutePath + "/" + "Album";
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format(MainPage.data + contador + "_frente.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                        await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fileStream);


fileStream.Close();
image.Recycle();

var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                        var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
                        intent.SetData(uri);
                        Forms.Context.SendBroadcast(intent);
```

Alguém sabe se tem alguma solução para isso?